# How to use animation-list in android studio

Tags: android

I am  developing an app in which i want to use frame animation. for this i am using animation-list. I am using android studio in which i created an anim folder inside the res folder.now i m not able to add any item. studio does not showing any tag like item when i pressed ctrl + space.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:oneshot="false">


</animation-list>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to create `anim` folder. You have to paste the images and resource xmls in `drawable` folder. If you do not have **drawable** folder then create one inside of your **res** folder.

I have pasted 4 png images and a spin_animation.xml file inside of the drawable folder.

**spin_animation.xml**

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/selected" android:oneshot="false">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ani4" android:duration="500" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ani3" android:duration="500" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ani2" android:duration="500" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ani1" android:duration="500" />
</animation-list>
```

Suppose you want to replace a imageView

```
ImageView gyroView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.gyro);
```

to show animation. Set the background of that imageView

```
gyroView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.spin_animation);
```

Create an Animation Drawable object based on this background:

```
AnimationDrawable gyroAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) gyroView.getBackground();
```

Start the animation:

```
gyroAnimation.start();
```

For detail help [check this](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-quick-tip-creating-frame-animations--mobile-15044).

Answer (score 1):

in Android Studio, put the xml file in the `res/drawable/` directory of your Module.

See these google offical doc below:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawable-animation.html